# Go mod private repo reads wrong path in cloudbuild

Tags: go, google-cloud-build, go-modules

I'm attempting to build a go project in google cloudbuild that uses a private repo but when go attempts to download the module it fails to find the revision and it's looking in the wrong path. I followed the instructions provided by google https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/access-private-github-repos. And I tested it by running the same build in docker on cloudbuild which succeeds. Here's the error I'm seeing.

```
go: github.com/company/repo/logging/v2@v2.0.6: reading github.com/company/repo/logging/logging/go.mod at revision logging/v2.0.6: unknown revision logging/v2.0.6
```

I'm not sure why it's attempt to go to logging/logging/go.mod that never existed.

Comment: Does the tag v2.0.6 exist?

Comment: The tag is logging/v2.0.6 because it is in a multi module repo.

Comment: The go mod file looks like this:
`github.com/company/repo/logging/v2 v2.0.6`

Comment: Is `logging` your repo name? In that case this would work. In case the module logging is a sub module of `repo` then try ```github.com/company/repo/v2/logging```

Comment: The repo has a module located ate repo/logging and there is a go.mod file in it that declares the module `github.com/company/repo/logging/v2`. I.e. there is no v2 folder

Comment: Can you share your cloud build file?

Comment: Sorry, I ended up switching to a docker build and that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround I ended up switching to a docker build and that worked.